# Random order not working correctly when using default loop + $query->set

Tags: custom-taxonomy, order, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to use `orderby => rand` on a custom taxonomy page, but it's not working correctly.

On other pages I use below piece of code to show my posts from a custom post type:

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'post_type'         => 'mycustomposttype',
        'orderby'           => 'rand(1234)',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'paged'             => $paged,
    );
     
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="pagintion">

            <?php

                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                     
                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                     'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                     'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                     'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
                ) );

            ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, I'm using `rand(1234)` instead of just `rand`. This is because I need the pagination to work correctly in combination with the random posts functionality. I've got this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489204/11538448

Now, on my custom taxonomy page (`taxonomy-mycustomtaxonomy.php`) I'm using the default WP loop and modifying the query in `functions.php` with `pre_get_posts` & `$query->set`. This is what I have now:

```
function alter_custom_tax_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tax('mycustomtaxonomy') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'mycustomposttype' ) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand(1234)' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_custom_tax_query' );
```

Here, the `rand` function is working, but when I try to use `rand(1234)` it stops working. Can anyone help me with this? I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have  you tried `RAND(x)` instead of `rand(x)`? Keep in mind that the cost of `rand` is extreme, it involves copying the entire posts table into a temporary database table then randomly shuffling the temporary table and running the query on that instead. It's super super expensive. It can be as much as 10000x faster to just pick a random date between now and when the site started and show the first post after that date that matches

Comment: @DeltaG, if the `pre_get_posts` doesn't work, try using a higher priority value, e.g. `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_custom_tax_query', 20 );` because a plugin/code might be overriding the query args. But are you sure `rand` (without custom seed) works there?